# How do I assign machines to a VLAN based on machine authentication and user authentication using a NPS RADIUS server?

Tags: vlan, authentication, radius, access-control

We have company-issued laptops that users can log into using smart cards. Using the Tunnel-PVT-Groupd-ID RADIUS element, we can assign the machine to a VLAN based on the authenticated user. However, we only certain machines to be able to be placed on that VLAN when that user logs in.

Is there a way to assign a machine to a VLAN based on both the certificate installed on the machine for machine authentication and the logged in user using NPS?

Comment: You need to give us more information. What is your network topology, network device model, and network device configurations. Whether or not you can do this is dependent on the information you provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you’ll want to use EAP chaining by using EAP-FAST which allows you to link the user and machine authentications.

Comment: It looks like Windows NPS doesn't support EAP-FAST V2, although after reading about it this looks like what we want. Are there any NPS-compatible solutions that you are aware of?

Comment: I'm not aware of any options other than EAP-FAST for chaining.

Comment: There's a proposed standard for EAP-FASTv2 which will be called EAP-TEAP

[link]https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7170

Currently MS support only TTLS, PEAP & TLS

[link]https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/hh945104(v=ws.11)